# Finding when requests are met or exceeded by customer by month

Tags: sql, dremel

I have a table that has customers and I want to find what month the customer met or exceeded a certain number of requests.

The table has customer_id a timestamp of each request.

What I am looking for is the month (or day) that the customer met or exceeded 10000 requests. I've tried to get a running total in place but this just isn't working for me. I've left it in the code in case someone knows how I can do this.

What I have is the following:

```
SELECT 
       customer_id
       , DATE_TRUNC(CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(created_timestamp) AS DATE), MONTH) as cMonth
       , COUNT(created_timestamp) as searchCount
--     , SUM(COUNT (DISTINCT(created_timestamp))) OVER (ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as RunningTotal2
FROM customer_requests.history.all
GROUP BY distributor_id, cMonth
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1 DESC;
```

The representation I am after is something like this.

```
customer    requests    cMonth       totalRequests
cust1       6000         2017-10-01  6000
cust1       4001         2017-11-01  10001
cust2       4000         2017-10-01  4000
cust2       4000         2017-11-01  8000
cust2       4000         2017-12-01  12000
cust2       3000         2017-12-01  3000
cust2       3000         2017-12-01  6000
cust2       3000         2017-12-01  9000
cust2       3000         2017-12-01  12000
```

Comment: What version of SQL?  MS, MY, Oracle other?  Also I do not see a where clause?  If you want only ones over a certain number you need to add that to your where caluse

Comment: Please tag your database

Comment: Hi, why dont you try grouping by customer and the day, sum up the requests and add a having clause where you filter the summed up requests. You also can use MIN to avoid having more than result row per customer and day.

Comment: Are you really using Dremel or BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, try this (adjusting the cutoff at the top to get the number of transactions you need; right now it looks for the thousandth transaction per customer).

Note that this will not return customers who have not exceeded your cutoff, and assumes that each transaction has a unique date (or is issued a sequential ID number to break ties if there can be ties on date).

```
DECLARE @cutoff INT = 1000;
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT customer_id,
           transaction_ID,
           transaction_date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_date, transaction_ID) AS RN,
           COUNT(transaction_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS TotalTransactions
    FROM #test)
SELECT DISTINCT
       customer_id,
       transaction_date as CutoffTransactionDate,
       TotalTransactions
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = @cutoff;
```

How it works:

`row_number` assigns a unique sequential identifier to each of a customer's transactions, in the order in which they were made.  `count` tells you the total number of transactions a person made (assuming again one record per transaction - otherwise you would need to calculate this separately, since `distinct` won't work with the `partition`).

Then the second `select` returns the 1,000th (or however many you specify) row for each customer and its date, along with the total for that customer.

Comment: Assuming not using SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution.

```
SELECT
  customerid
 ,SUM(requests) sumDay
 ,created_timestamp
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 
  customerid,
  created_timestamp
HAVING SUM(requests) >= 10000;
```

Its pretty simple. You just group according to your needs, sum up the requests and select the rows that meet your HAVING clause.
You can try the query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fafa4/6/0).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cumulative sum, you can use window functions.  In Standard SQL, this looks like:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       DATE_TRUNC(CAST(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(created_timestamp) AS DATE), MONTH) as cMonth
       COUNT(*) as searchCount,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(created_timestamp) as runningtotal
FROM customer_requests.history.all
GROUP BY distributor_id, cMonth
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1 DESC;
```